# Clarity needed on stackoverflow.blog comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, blog, guidelines

I'll be honest, yesterday's blog post, *[The Loop #2: Understanding Site Satisfaction, Summer 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/22/the-loop-2-understanding-site-satisfaction-summer-2019)*, didn't sit well with me. So much so that I decided to comment. My comment represented the very first time I've spoken up about what I've seen going as of late on SO.

Unfortunately, my comment has been *awaiting moderation* since 06:17 EST on January 23rd.

*I believe that we need some documented comment guidelines.*

I don't like the idea that a slightly critical, but respectful comment doesn't make it through the moderator filter.

What's the end goal of the blog? Is it simply to disseminate information without critical (in the best sense of the word) interaction? Great...let us know.

It's certainly not lost on me that a comment which discusses *trust issues* does not get posted.

**How about those comment guidelines?**

Comment in question:

> Recent events have made it difficult to trust the SO team. With that
>   in mind, publishing content like this, without any information
>   regarding how this survey was conducted, how the questions were
>   framed, and to whom the survey was sent (and how those people were
>   chosen), makes me seriously doubt the results.
>
> I’ve been a member for 8 years and 8 months. I don’t have the highest
>   rep on the site, but I’ve answered 692 questions, and have a reach of
>   ~10.4 million people. I didn’t receive the survey, but if I did, I
>   would have answered “Unwelcoming community” as well, but not for the
>   reason(s) that this post is indicating.
>
> As a long-time contributor, I feel unwelcome by leadership. The
>   tremendous effort and care that we as a community have invested to
>   make SO successful almost seems despised by the current regime. From
>   the outside looking in, SO appears to be imploding, and the
>   destruction is blamed on an “unwelcoming community” and
>   “over-moderation” instead of poor leadership decisions. Odd, isn’t it,
>   that the unwelcoming community that’s being vilified is what made SO
>   what it is today?

Comment: @DavisBroda, I hear what you're saying, but I'm not sure that what I've seen today backs that up. There were comments on the blog already when I posted at 06:17 EST this morning, and several comments after I posted. Still, if that's the way it works, it would be nice to see that documented somewhere, along with comment guidelines. Also, I still don't see mine...maybe it hasn't propagated my way yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where did my blog comment go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337773/where-did-my-blog-comment-go)

Comment: The comment is only visible through the link in the question, and with a remark *"Your comment is awaiting moderation."*.

Comment: The Stack Overflow blog is [based on WordPress](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/31/the-secret-index-of-all-stack-overflow-blog-posts/) and [notification about new comments is likely by email](https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-email-comments-notifications/).

Comment: Pretty disappointed that this was closed as a dupe. One of the supposed dupes doesn't have an answer, and the other answer is inadequate. My comment is still not visible, except by using the link in my question. **It's clear that any comment perceived as too negative is being censored**. Let's address is. Document the standard.

Comment: For all those who commented - it's been a couple days now. Still no comment. Do you believe that my comment merited being rejected by a moderator? This is a dangerous precedent for a community-driven site

Comment: On any other company blog, this is exactly the behavior i would expect. Hide stuff that will look bad to current and/or future customers regardless of how right the comments are. it's not surprising given the company's shift from community building to profit making over the past 4 years for them to handle blog comments in this way.

Comment: @user400654 - I don't disagree with you. Give that this is SO though, I think my request to document and to make clear comment guidelines is both reasonable and necessary.

Comment: it's simply unreasonable to expect that to ever occur, at least under the current business model.